# Java 8 LocalDateTime and DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, java-8

below piece of code thorws exception..am i doing something wrong here?

```
DateTimeFormatter  FORMATTER    = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                                        "ddMMuuuuHHmmssSSS"
                                    );      
    String currentTime=FORMATTER.format(LocalDateTime.now());
    System.out.println(currentTime);
    LocalDateTime parsedTime=LocalDateTime.parse(currentTime,FORMATTER);


09042016161444380
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '09042016161444380' could not be parsed at index 4
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
```

Comment: I *suspect* the problem is that the parser doesn't know where the year is going to stop - it could be 20161 rather than 2016. If you add a `'T'` between the date and time parts, it works. Personally I'd strongly advise you to use an ISO-8601 format if at all possible...

Comment: thanks Jon but parser should read the pattern which says that year is 4 char, hence should stop at 2016.

Comment: @Krishan no, not exactly. 4 or more means interpret the year literally, so it would parse the year as `2016161444380` - which is quite far in the future.

Answer (score 2):

As [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) mentioned in the above comment, with `uuuu` the parser doesn't know where the year is going to stop. This is because more than 2 `u's` or `y's` are interpreted literally by the parser.

From JavaDoc of `Year`:

> For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D.

Hence, it should work fine if you change it to `ddMMuuHHmmssSSS` or `ddMMyyHHmmssSSS` from `ddMMuuuuHHmmssSSS` as in this instance the parser knows where to stop exactly.