# DateTimeFormatter not able to parse String to LocalDateTime

Tags: java

I am trying to create a LocalDateTime object from a string that is coming from another system (i.e. I don't have the ability to control it).  The `LocalDateTime.parse(String, DateTimeFormatter)` method of Java 8 is not correctly able to parse my string.  An example of the date string would be `20190813074127111` and the pattern I am using is `yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS`. The error is that `Text '20190813074127111' could not be parsed at index 0`

I have validated my letters in my DateTimeFormatter pattern are correct using the documentation for the letters.  I have seen many questions and answers on Stack Overflow very similar to this but none have exactly solved my issue.

I thought that [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515792/java-8-localdatetime-and-datetimeformatter) was similar to what I am experiencing, which says that the  entire String could be being evaluated as a year as I am using yyyy in my pattern string. I tried modifying the pattern to both `yyMMddHHmmssSSS` and `uuMMddHHmmssSSS`; in both cases the exception changes to `Text '20190813074127111' could not be parsed at index 15`

I have tried trimming the SSS at the end of my pattern and removing the milliseconds from the input string and that correctly creates a LocalDateTime with the correct date and time, but I don't have the precision provided with the milliseconds, and this use case should be as precise as possible.

I had to remove some details since I am doing this for a company, but this is identical to the use case I am trying to accomplish

```java
public class MyClass {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATETIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");

    public LocalDateTime parseStringToDate(String input) {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(input, DATETIME_FORMATTER);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the DateTimeFormatBuilder:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
        .toFormatter();
```

Related post: [Is java.time failing to parse fraction-of-second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588051/is-java-time-failing-to-parse-fraction-of-second)

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. It is to note that `LocalDateTime` does nano of seconds instead of milliseconds like the old `Date` did

Comment: Correct, but this is what we have the duplicate mechanism for. Please flag as a duplicate instead of writing a new duplicate answer in this and similar cases. Readers are helped better when led to the place where we have all the information about this question gathered.

Comment: Perfect answer.  Thanks for linking the related post that's one that I did not see in the several stack overflow that I saw

Comment: Tips: (a) Such output could be made to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, specifically the "basic" variation that minimizes delimiters, by putting a `T` in between the date portion and the time-of-day portion. (b) If this value represents a moment in UTC, it should have a `Z` appended, meaning UTC, pronounced “Zulu”.